# meaning of the phrase "peel one's banana" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course Biology](https://youtu.be/dPKvHrD1eS4). It is at around 7 second. Here is the context:

> How long have you been waiting in this line. I have been here for like 15 minutes and it is freaking freezing out here. I mean, whose **banana** do you got to **peel** in order to get into this club.

Comment: Is this the same guy who did crash course history? it sounds like him. [I haven't watched any of them, nor am I likely to ;)

Comment: He is his brother

Comment: What does a banana resemble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the expression **peel someone's banana** is new to me, the context makes it clear that the questioner, who is freezing cold, wants to know what he/she has to do - and for whom - in order to obtain prompt entry to the club.

It suggests that some sycophantic action might impress the club manager sufficiently to allow the questioner in.

It is more an expression of frustration, a rhetorical question, than a request for an answer.

A more vulgar and popular way of expressing things might be to ask: *whose butt/bum do I have to kiss in order to get in?*

Comment: It's a euphemistic version of the actual question. https://books.google.com/books?id=iOB13d-TCf4C&pg=PA47&dq=%22do+you+have+to+blow%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxoKKyvvvcAhXFslkKHb5lA-gQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22do%20you%20have%20to%20blow%22&f=false